# Send file through Django Rest

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, storage

I need to download image object from vary object storage buckets, and send that to a user through Django Rest Framework.

I have something like that:

```
if request.method == 'GET':

    # Get object using swiftclient
    conn = swiftclient.client.Connection(**credentials)
    container, file = 'container_name', 'object_name'
    _, data = conn.get_object(container, file)

    # Send object to the browser
    return Response(data, content_type="image/png")
```

`data` variable contains bytes type.

While testing I'm receiving error:
`'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x89 in position 0: invalid start byte`

What can be solution for this problem?

Comment: Please, post the stack trace and the version of python.

Comment: `import base64`                                                                                                       
`data = base64.b64encode(data)`

Comment: @JoseKilo it's Python 3.5

Comment: @AnupYadav encoding the data works. I received status code = 200 while testing.
But is there any other possibilities for sending the image without using base64 library?

Comment: That's great! Woule like me to put this solution as answer so you can accept. I don't other solution than this

Comment: @sorryMike What happned?

Comment: @AnupYadav instead comment under the question, write your post as an answer for the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to import base64 and need to convert byte data into base64 encoded format, to resolve that issue.

```
import base64 
data = base64.b64encode(data)
```

==== OR =====

I respect @Will Keeling answer and would like to have that in my post as well.

```
from django.http import HttpResponse

return HttpResponse(data, content_type="image/png")
```

Comment: Negative marker tell me the reason. Without reason looks unethical.

Answer (score 11):

If you're looking to pass the image straight through Django Rest Framework to the user, it may be more appropriate to use an `HttpResponse`.

```
from django.http import HttpResponse

return HttpResponse(data, content_type="image/png")
```

Django Rest Framework's own `Response` will try and render the binary data which may cause the encoding issue you're seeing.